# RTD equivalent for LibreOffice

Tags: excel, libreoffice, rtd

Is there an LibreOfficeCalc function doing the same thing as RTD?

I could not find one.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO and the development is not started yet (at the time of writing).

Reference: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions/not_yet_implemented

Comment: anyways, you can implement an add-in function with variable result https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Variable_Results and do whatever is required to get the value in your own code there. Also, DDE, which is RTD's predecessor in a way, seems to be supported in OpenOffice